# Calculation of inverse regression

Tags: regression

I am reading the paper *on consistency and sparsity for sliced inverse regression in high dimensions* (https://doi.org/10.1214/17-AOS1561). I'm curious about the conclusion on the page 585

> Let $y=\beta^Tx+\varepsilon$, where $x$ follows from a multivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and $\varepsilon$ is a normal error. Simple calculation shows that $E(x|y)=\frac{y\Sigma\beta}{var(y)}$.

How to derive this conclusion? What I only know is the classical sliced inverse regression conclusion that $E(x|y)$ satisfies
$$ E(x|y) = \Sigma\beta(\beta^{T}\Sigma\beta)^{-1}\beta^T E(x|y).
$$
Is there a similar conclusion when we relax the distribution condition from normal to elliptical distribution?